# How to convert character into date in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a character value generated using `date_format()` function into a Date value but I get null as a result
Following is my query:

```
select Str_to_date(date_format(cast(last_update as datetime), '%D %M %Y %T'),'%d/%m/%y') from address;
```

and result is `NULL`

is there any way to convert resulting character value generated from date_format function into a date?

Comment: What do the values of `last_update` look like? Can you please post some examples?

Comment: If cast(last_update as datetime) results in NULL, then every subsequent operation is going to result in NULL.

Comment: Last_update value is datetime value only. example: '2006-02-15 04:45:30'.

Answer (score 0):

If last_update is datetime, then you can simply use

```
SELECT 
    last_update, DATE(last_update) 
from address;
```

If it is varchar of format '2006-02-15 04:45:30', then, you can use

```
SELECT 
    last_update, DATE(CAST(last_update as datetime)) 
from address;
```

**Reference**:

[DATE function on MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: It is not working and throwing syntax error.                 Query: select date(date_format(cast(last_update as datetime), '%D %M %Y %T'),'%d/%m/%y') from address                                     Error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%d/%m/%y') from address' at line 1 0.016 sec

Comment: The query you ran is not the same as it is in my answer. I did not use the date_format function.